# Create a new table from merging two tables with union

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with the same columns.

I can merge them with `UNION`

```
select * from  table1
union
select * from table2;
```

How do I create a new table with the same contents and columns as that query?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) statement.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  SELECT * FROM table1
    UNION
  SELECT * FROM table2;
```

Comment: Yes Its working i dont know why i was tryng CREATE TABLE new_table(
  SELECT * FROM table1
    UNION
  SELECT * FROM table2);

Answer (score 7):

```
create table new_table as
select col1, col2 from table1 
union 
select col1, col2 from table2
```

Make sure you select same set of columns from tables in union.

Comment: mysql throws an error if you try to wrap the union query in parenthesis. omitting the parenthesis did the trick for me, as suggested by @devart's answer

Answer (score 1):

Or even you can explicitly define create table (we generally use in our project).

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS auditlog (

user_id varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',

user_ip varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',

........
........

KEY ie1 (user_id) )

union=(auditlog_2,auditlog_3,auditlog_4) engine=merge insert_method=last;